# hot and cold water reversed on shower unknown brand

Tags: shower

I purchased a house and the hot and cold are reversed in the shower.  I am not sure what brand the shower is as there are no markings.   I am including a picture.  I am not sure if anyone has a link to a video on how to switch the value.  It looks like it has threads and maybe screws off but not sure.

Thanks
[image]

Comment: This can occur if the cartridge is installed incorrectly

Comment: A wider view image may help, as well as a picture of the actual plumbing on the other side of the wall, if it's at all accessible. Please [edit] those into your original post

Answer (score 1):

Unscrew the holding ring. Pull the cartridge out. Turn it 180 degrees. Put it back.

If the valve is made for it, then this will work. If not, then the cartridge will only go in one way and your shower is reversed.

Note: Depending on age and water purity, the valve might be difficult to pull out. Using a build-up remover can be helpful. If you break the cartridge, since the brand is unknown, a new cartridge will be unlocateable. The 'forever' warranty many faucet manufacturers are giving is contingent upon you correctly identifying the make model of your faucet. Delta still does it the old fashioned way -- Decent purchase cost, no warranty, purchase the parts off the store shelf. Parts for the foriegn super cheap faucets are unavailable. Others, Price-Pfister etc., require you to know what you have.